# Is there a keyboard shortcut to switch the cursor between panels of iPad split screen?

Tags: ipad, ipados, magic-keyboard-ipad

Is there a way to switch back and forth between two functionalities open in split screen easily on the iPad?

Comment: Can we assume you’re using the magic keyboard or is this a USB connected or other Bluetooth keyboard (shouldn’t matter, tbh.  Just curious)

Answer (score 1):

> Control Option Left Bracket and Control Option Right Bracket should allow the user to switch between the two apps displayed
> […]
> If you […] try it twice, you should find it indeed moves you to the application on the other side of the screen.

https://www.applevis.com/forum/switching-between-apps-split-view-ipad-using-keyboard-commands

Comment: Doesn’t seem to work for me.